# sildeUp is not a function in VueJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am a bit new to **VueJS** and I used jQuery code inside `mounted` function as:

```
mounted () {
  $(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function() {
    $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);
    if (
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .hasClass("active")
    ) {
      $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
      $(this)
        .next(".sidebar-submenu")
        .slideDown(200);
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .addClass("active");
    }
  });
}
```

The class `active` is working but `slideUp` and `slideDown` not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: This sort of thing is pretty common for new Vue users, and it'll really impede your understanding of and ability to use the framework.  Do yourself a favor and remove jQuery from your development pipeline until you've got a stronger grasp of how Vue itself works; most of the DOM manipulation you're doing would be better done via the component template, and  the event handling via Vue methods, instead of bypassing the framework using jQuery.

Comment: I have many links in the HTML template I have to bind to click event one by one what about that? I used jQuery so that I have to write one line of code and then all elements with that class can be used but in Vue I have to write `@click` on each element!

Comment: If you placed this in the `mounted()` of a reusable component, you're bound for disaster. At least limit the application of your bound events by passing `this.$el` as the second param in your jQuery selectors, like this: `$('.slidebar-droopdown a', this.$el)`. This way, you're only binding one event/link in your component, not one event/link * n components for all links in the page.

Comment: But, seriously, you might want to read up on [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). If you're so keen on using jQuery, at least do it the right way. And, actually, I believe that's the reason your events don't work. Vue updates (as in, replaces) the elements and your initially bound events are gone. The answer is using delegated events bound on an element that's in DOM at the time of binding ***and*** the time of the event.

Comment: Well, instead of lots of individual @click events, you probably want to be drawing those elements using a v-for loop so you can write both the DOM elements *and* the click handler in one line.   Vue (and other SPA frameworks) require a very different approach compared to jQuery, you have some habits to unlearn.  Mixing vue and jquery like this will cause all kinds of confusing bugs when vue starts trying to update the DOM too, and overwrites your jquery bindings that it doesn't know about or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I was copied bootstrap's JavaScript section and I noticed there is the **Slim version of jQuery**, I replaced that I now all working fine!